# Print variable within html code

Tags: php, html, echo

```
$a="something";
echo ' <div id="content">$a, but not sure how to do it</div>'
```

How can I print `$a`'s value inside echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways

```
1) use " instead of '

echo " <div id='content'>$a, but not sure how to do it</div>"

2) use {} with " if you are want to print something complex and want your editor to format it correctly. most of the time i use it with arrays or when calling a function ex. {$arr['a']} instead of $arr['a'].

 echo " <div id='content'>{$a}, but not sure how to do it</div>"

3) just do this 

echo ' <div id="content">' . $a . ', but not sure how to do it</div>'
```

Comment: {$a} doesn't print its value.

Comment: oops. :\ my bad. editing now.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo " <div id=\"content\">$a, but not sure how to do it</div>";
```

Please read the difference between [single and double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<div id=\"content\">" . $a . ", but not sure how to do it </div>";
```

The \'s are escape sequences that allow you to have quotation marks within strings (otherwise they would terminate the string). The .'s are concatenation.